# proving any two non-empty subsets $A, B$ of the Real Number space are open if $A \times B$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having a bit of trouble proving this theorem.
I can visualize that $A \times B$ is a rectangle of points in $\mathbb R^2$ and that not all of $A \times B$'s limit points are in $A \times B$, but I'm at a loss on how I should use the fact that a point in $A \times B$ can be contained in a ball of some positive radius and still be a subset of $A \times B$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider the projection maps $\pi_A: A \times B \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_A: A \times B \rightarrow B$. What will they do to an open ball contained in $A \times B$?

Comment: Thank you for that hint, Secret Math.
To my understanding, these projection maps should generate a subset of the subsets they project to, ie. pi_A(a,b) creates a subset of A.
A is an interval since A is a subset of R. Does this mean that these functions, which should be continuous (?), will map (a,b) in AxB to a in A, and these a in A should be contained in an open interval of some positive radius and still be in A, much like (a,b) was contained in an open ball of the same positive radius?
I'm sorry if this sounds messy, I'm trying to articulate my thoughts into a coherent proof.

Comment: @GrantS You basically got the idea, just need to put it into better written mathematical language.